# C# Winforms with EF6 and .Net Version 4.0 - Not able to open executable - Issue with EF6 connectivity between host and DB Server

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6, dbconnection

I have got a simple Winforms app which is programmed around Entity framework 6 and runtime environment .Net 4.0. i have provided access to the release folder to certain set of users, however they are unable to open the executable.

Below is the folder structure of the executable which users are provided.
[image]

when the users tried to open the exe. They are provided with bellow details.
[image]

and when tried to expand "view problem details", below is the content

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:                        CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:                       XXX_v4.exe
  Problem Signature 02:                       1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03:                       57517229
  Problem Signature 04:                       mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05:                       4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06:                       53b50a71
  Problem Signature 07:                       4763
  Problem Signature 08:                       9d
  Problem Signature 09:                       System.Security.Security
  OS Version:                                          6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:                                             2057
  Additional Information 1:                  0a9e
  Additional Information 2:                  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3:                  0a9e
  Additional Information 4:                  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

*(Not sure if this helps, but for info)* Users are provided with non-persistent desktops where OS is loaded as a package solution.

**EDIT 1** 
Appconfig file : 
[image]
Not sure what i'm missing.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does your host desktop have access to the data server? Check the connectivity to your server and the connectionstring the application is using

Comment: @jcvegan : Yes, i think that's what the problem is. I have tested with a blank win form to load and it worked. So its something to do with DB connectivity (with EF6). Server connectivity is fine, because i can connect to server from my machine. So its to do with the connectionstring the application is using. I have edited my question with the connection string i'm using. How can i resolve the connection string issue if the same works for me and not for host. Any ideas on this please?

Comment: @jcvegan : I have tried to generate EDM file to form connection string using Windows login and SQL Server userid / password. Both of them resulting the same. Do i need to install any driver to contact SQL server from host machines (which i guess not required) ?